# Matlab compiler (mcc) not including referenced functions

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

I am trying to compile a matlab source file (.m) into a standalone application (on linux). In my .m file I am calling a function (specifically from a library called [MALSAR](http://www.malsar.org/)) which in turn seem to be using some compiled libraries (.mexglx  .mexmaci64  .mexw32  .mexw64). When I compiled my source file, I included all the subdirectories under MALSAR package using "-I" option as follows

`mcc -mv -I <dir1> -I <dir2> .... myfile.m`

The compilation does not give an warnings, but when I execute the standalone executable, I get a *MATLAB:fileHasDisappeared* error. I am using **mcc Version 4.18.**

The detailed error out is included below.

```
The file
   '/home/acharuva/Projects/scot/ext/MALSAR/functions/joint_feature_learning/Logistic_L21.m'
   is not in the application's expanded CTF archive at
    '/home/acharuva/.mcrCache8.1/run_l20'.
This is typically caused by calls to ADDPATH in your startup.m or matlabrc.m files. Please see the compiler documentation and use the ISDEPLOYED function to ensure ADDPATH commands are not executed by deployed applications.
Previously accessible file "/home/acharuva/Projects/scot/ext/MALSAR/functions/joint_feature_learning/Logistic_L21.m" is now inaccessible.

Error in run_l21_cross (line 34)

MATLAB:fileHasDisappeared
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: So obvious and maybe silly question would be - Do you have `ADDPATH` command in any of those m-files that are part of this project?

Comment: My bad, I failed to check for the obvious :). Thanks a lot @Divakar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was obvious from the error messages and as @Divakar pointed out, this was being caused by addpath() function in the code, which I failed to check for. Fixing that fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

At Matlab .m file cover ADDPATH with isdeployed flag. Otherwise, when code building from compiler it gives "Previously accessible file" error.
For fixing it:

%isdeployed=false means file run from matlab app, if true means run from compiler

```
  if(isdeployed==false)

    addpath(...);

    end
```